# How to save data values without subscribing through MQTT?

Tags: python, mqtt

I'm doing a project that consists of an RPi and an ESP8266. My RPi acts as the broker. I send data from my ESP to RPi through MQTT by subscribing. When I don't subscribe and run my code the data is lost until the point I subscribe. Is there a way to save the data values in the RPi as a file and when I subscribe, the previous data isn't lost as it is saved?

Comment: Go look at MQTT QOS levels. But as a rule MQTT brokers do not queue data unless there is a persistent subscription at QOS 1 or 2

Answer (score 0):

There needs to be a subscriber for the broker to not discard messages. If you want to keep all of them, you will need to have a subscriber that records messages and can play them back later or otherwise allow you to process the data.

Comment: Not totally true, if there has been a subscriber at greater than QOS 0 then the broker will queue messages for when it reconnects